# I want to get number and name of columns from PHPExcel class

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, xls

I want to get number and name of columns from PHPExcel class and want to create mysql database with same columnname as field name and copy xls file data in that database. In its example I can get no of rows and columns but I am not getting name of columns and want to create database as well, so please help. Here is code

```
    <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>PHPExcel Reader Example #19</title>

</head>
<body>

<h1>PHPExcel Reader Example #19</h1>
<h2>Reading WorkSheet information without loading entire file</h2>
<?php

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


$inputFileType = 'Excel5';
//  $inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
//  $inputFileType = 'Excel2003XML';
//  $inputFileType = 'OOCalc';
//  $inputFileType = 'Gnumeric';
$inputFileName = './sampleData/playnew.xls';

echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' information using IOFactory with a defined reader type of ',$inputFileType,'<br />';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$worksheetData = $objReader->listWorksheetInfo($inputFileName);

echo '<h3>Worksheet Information</h3>';
echo '<ol>';
foreach ($worksheetData as $worksheet) {
    echo '<li>', $worksheet['worksheetName'], '<br />';
    echo 'Rows: ', $worksheet['totalRows'], ' Columns: ', $worksheet['totalColumns'], '<br />';
    echo 'Cell Range: A1:', $worksheet['lastColumnLetter'], $worksheet['totalRows'];
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';



?>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unless you consider the names of the columns as `A`, `B`, `C` etc (the names that MS Excel uses for columns), then what exactly do you mean by column names?

Comment: I want to use first row of excel file as a field name in Mysql database so need to collect those names from excel files as array I think and than create new table with that name, hope this clear what I am looking for. Thanks for taking interest.

Comment: Well you'll have to actually load the spreadsheet to get that information

Comment: I already load file check this $inputFileName = './sampleData/playnew.xls';

Comment: Nothing in your code actually __loads__ the file; all you're doing is getting the spreadsheet meta information and summary: take a look at the [PHPExcel Docs](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation%20Reading%20Spreadsheet%20Files)